# Export data from Google SpreadSheet to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have big Google Spreadseet (about 50 colums and about 50 sheets). Can I export data from tables to SQL database? May be there are script opportunities or anothers...

Thanks in advance, Dmitry.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to use Google Apps Script.

The `SpreadsheetService` will easily open and read the spreadsheet, then you can use the `JDBC` service to connect to Cloud SQL.